# why does google.com redirect if URL contains /amp followed by a schemeless domain name and optional resource?

Tags: google, url-redirection

Google recently announced a 'quiz' - more of a tutorial - on identifying phishing email: https://phishingquiz.withgoogle.com

It includes a sample URL: `https://google.com/amp/tinyurl.com/y7u8ewlr`

When followed this is converted into: `https://www.google.com/url?q=http://tinyurl.com/y7u8ewlr` and a Redirect Notice page is shown with this content:

> The page you were on is trying to send you to http://tiny url.com/y7u8ewlr.
> If you do not want to visit that page, you can return to the previous page.

Following tinyurl link takes you to a Jigsaw page - Jigsaw and google seem to have cooperated in producing this quiz.

Putting in any schemeless domain name and optional resources (eg. ibm.com) work as well. https://www.google.com/amp/ibm.com

Why might google.com perform these redirections?
Are they a security risk (as they can make any URL appear to be from google)?

Answer (score 3):

[Google's FAQ about this topic](https://sites.google.com/site/bughunteruniversity/nonvuln/open-redirect) includes:

> [...] Some members of the security community argue that the
>   redirectors aid phishing, because users may be inclined to trust the
>   mouse hover tooltip on a link and then fail to examine the address bar
>   once the navigation takes place.
>
> Our take on this is that tooltips are not a reliable security
>   indicator, and can be tampered with in many ways; so, we invest in
>   technologies to detect and alert users about phishing and abuse, but
>   we generally hold that a small number of properly monitored
>   redirectors offers fairly clear benefits and poses very little
>   practical risk.

They apparently have sufficient business reason to offer the redirects to continue offering it as a service, and dealing with the fallout from offering it.

Comment: I found a discussion on ycombinator about: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18972512